# i want a X-OR code for neural network in matlab

Tags: matlab, biological-neural-network

i m doing project on neural network.
i want a demo code for AND,OR,X-OR  or any SMALL APPLICATION in matlab.
thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple example of the XOR problem (non-linearly separable):

```
input = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]';    %#'
target = [0 1 1 0];               %# target = xor(input(1,:), input(2,:));

%# create ANN: 1 hidden layer with 2 neurons, 
%# and an output layer with a sigmoid transfer function
net = newpr(input, target, 2);
net.divideFcn = '';               %# no data split (training/testing/validation)
net.trainParam.epochs = 50;

net = init(net);
[net,tr] = train(net, input, target);
output = sim(net, input);

[err,cm] = confusion(target,output)
```

with a perfect result of:

```
err =
     0
cm =
     2     0
     0     2
```

It requires the Neural Network Toolbox